# Getting a Value to use in an update script in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass a value from a select into an update script. I have a page that keeps a members information. I would like to keep the user name and password on a different table. However I am having problems getting the id from the member table to pass to the user id table. Here is what I am doing. The first query is working fine and adding the member information to the member table. It is where I try to do the select and the second update is where I am having problems.

```
$user_id;

$sql = "INSERT INTO member_contact (mem_first_name, mem_last_name, mem_address_1, mem_address_2, mem_city, mem_state, mem_zip, mem_phone, mem_email)
VALUES ('$_POST[mem_fn]','$_POST[mem_ln]','$_POST[mem_add1]','$_POST[mem_add2]','$_POST[mem_city]','$_POST[mem_st]','$_POST[mem_zip]','$_POST[mem_ph]','$_POST[mem_email]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    //echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$selsql = "select mem_id into $user_id from member_contact 
where mem_first_name = '$_POST[mem_fn]'
and mem_last_name =  '$_POST[mem_ln]'";

if ($conn->query($selsql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'mem_id';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $selsql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$insql = "insert into user_info (mem_id, user_id, user_pass)
values('$user_id','$_post[us_id]','$_post[us_pass]')";

if ($conn->query($insql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'User name added';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();
```

Here is the error I am getting with this code.

Error: select mem_id into from member_contact where mem_first_name = 'Andy' and mem_last_name = 'D'
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from member_contact where mem_first_name = 'Andy' and mem_last_name = 'D'' at line 1User name added

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You never actually put a value in the `$user_id` variable.  You just have a line that does nothing more than declare it: `$user_id;`  Please note also that your code is *filled* with **SQL injection vulnerabilities**.  Users can basically execute any code they want on your database.

Comment: Also, you should be hashing your users' passwords. See http://php.net/password_hash

Comment: MySQL doesn't support the `SELECT ... INTO table` syntax. See the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: David do you have a sample of secure queries? Also I am trying to figure out how to past the value from the select to the $user_id.